# 3D Geometry concurrency problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, solid-geometry, centroid

$ABCD$ is a tetrahedron.
Let $K$ be the center of the incircle of $CBD$.
Let $M$ be the center of the incircle of $ABD$.
Let $L$ be the centroid of $DAC$.
Let $N$ be the centroid of $BAC$.

Suppose $AK$, $BL$, $CM$, $DN$ have one common point.

Is $ABCD$ necessarily regular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, $AC$ need not equal to other $5$ edges and the tetrahedron need not be regular.

As long as the remaining $5$ edges are equal in length, we have

- $BC = CD = DB \implies \triangle BCD$ is equilateral $\implies K$ coincides with centroid of $\triangle BCD$.
- $AB = BD = AD \implies \triangle ABD$ is equilateral $\implies M$ coincides with
  centroid of $\triangle ABD$.

The $4$ lines $AK, BL, CM, DN$ will then intersect at the centroid of tetrahedron $ABCD$.